# Rspec validate with_message test failing, despite correct message's pressence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

I have a test in Rspec meant to validate a specific validation message.  When I run the test suit, it fails.  But by the looks of the failure description, it looks like it should be passing.  Here is the test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  describe 'associations' do 
    it { should have_many(:created_projects) }
    it { should have_many(:collaborations) }
    it { should have_many(:projects) }
  end

  describe 'validations' do 
    it do 
      should validate_presence_of(:name).
      with_message("People will want to know who you are. Please include your name.")
    end
    it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
  end
end
```

ANd here is the failure message I get when I run my test suite:

Failure/Error:
       is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name).
         with_message(
           /People will want to know who you are. Please include your name./
         )

```
   User did not properly validate that :name cannot be empty/falsy,
   producing a custom validation error on failure.
     After setting :name to ‹nil›, the matcher expected the UserProfile to
     be invalid and to produce a validation error matching ‹/People will
     want to know who you are. Please include your name./› on :name. The
     record was indeed invalid, but it produced these validation errors
     instead:

     * email: ["can't be blank", "Please enter valid email address."]
     * name: ["People will want to know who you are. Please include your
       name."]
     * password: ["can't be blank"]
```

And here is how the validation is declared in the model `User.rb`

```
  validates_presence_of :name, 
    message: "People will want to know who you are.  Please include your name."
```

Any ideas why this test will not pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces for your `message` value look inconsistent. In your `User` model, looks like you have two spaces after `are.`

```
"People will want to know who you are.  Please include your name."
```

whereas in your spec file you have a single space

```
"People will want to know who you are. Please include your name."
```

They aren't the same string so the test is failing